# VB.NET http response

Tags: php, vb.net, http, webrequest

I am trying to post 2 variables to a php script and then return the text that is displayed on the website.

I VB6, I did it the following way, it worked perfectly fine.
Can somebody please tell me how to do this in VB.NET?

```
Public Function GetHTTPResponse() As String

Dim sPost$
sPost$ = "http://www.somedomain.com/somescript.php"
sPost$ = sPost$ & "?variable1=MYVAR1"
sPost$ = sPost$ & "&variable2=MYVAR2"

'=======================================================
'"?" Prefix 1st Variable, "&" prefix for subsequent vars
'=======================================================
Dim iPos&
iPos = InStr(sPost, "?")
If (iPos = 0) Then
    Exit Function
End If

Dim sDomain$
sDomain$ = Left$(sPost, (iPos - 1))

'====================================
'Pack the post data into a byte array
'====================================
Dim sPostData As String
sPostData = Right$(sPost, Len(sPost) - iPos)

Debug.Print sPostData

Dim bytpostdata() As Byte
pBuildPostData bytpostdata(), sPostData

'=============================
'Write the byte into a variant
'=============================
Dim varPostData As Variant
varPostData = bytpostdata
'=================
'Create the Header
'=================
Dim sHeader$
sHeader = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" + Chr(10) + Chr(13)
'=============
'Post the data
'=============
Dim xmlhttp As Object
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

xmlhttp.Open "POST", sDomain, False
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", sHeader
xmlhttp.sEnd varPostData

Dim sRet$
sRet = xmlhttp.responseText

GetHTTPResponse = sRet

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution here:

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/using-webclient-webrequest-webresponse-post-postdata-and-get-result-t1222629.html